# Different time taken by python script every time it is runned?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am working on a Opencv based Python project. I am working on program development which takes less time to execute. For that i have tested my small program print hello world on python to test the time taken to run the program. I had run many time and every time it run it gives me a different run time.

Can you explain me why a simple program is taking different time to execute?

I need my program to be independent of system processes ?

Comment: Can we add something in the program to run at constant time.

Comment: You could set a minimum time using a `time.sleep()` at the end if enough time hadn't passed yet.

Comment: I just need to make my program independent of computer processes. Is that possible

Answer (score 1):

Python gets different amounts of system resources depending upon what else the CPU is doing at the time. If you're playing Skyrim with the highest graphics levels at the time, then your script will run slower than if no other programs were open. But even if your task bar is empty, there may be invisible background processes confounding things.

If you're not already using it, consider using `timeit`. It performs multiple runs of your program in order to smooth out bad runs caused by a busy OS.

If you absolutely insist on requiring your program to run in the same amount of time every time, you'll need to use an OS that doesn't support multitasking. For example, DOS.